# Is there a web coding program which is named as Pascal?

Tags: java, pascal

Pascal, I am told that there is a Java-related.

Is there a web coding program which is named as Pascal?

Comment: Please elaborate, do you seek for Java framework named Pascal? What exactly they sad to you ? The only Pascal I'm aware of (beside 17th century scientist) is programming language completely unrelated to Java

Comment: What did you find when you searched the web?

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of [UCSD Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCSD_Pascal), which was compiled to p-code and run on a virtual machine in much the same way as Java is compiled to byte code to be executed by the JVM.
In fact, according to that Wikipedia page, James Gosling has cited UCSD Pascal, along
with Smalltalk, as part of his inspiration for design of the Java virtual machine.

Other than that, calling Pascal "Java-related" is a bit of a stretch.  I am not aware
of any particular usefulness of Pascal as a web programming language, although
one could certainly use it for CGI programs.

Answer (score 2):

[Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29) is a programming language that was first introduced to the world in 1970.  (It predates Java by 20 years or so.)

The original version of the language was designed and implemented by Nicolas Wirth.  The history was that Wirth was originally involved with IFIP 2.1 committee, and together with Tony Hoare developed the Algol-W language (based on the committee's Algol X draft).  Wirth then went on to design and implement Pascal, as a reaction to the complexity of IFIP 2.1's original Algol-68 spec.  Pascal took off in a big way in academic circles; e.g. as a teaching language.  I remember using Pascal on a CDC 6400 in ~1975 as an undergraduate.

(Algol-68 never went anywhere much.  I don't think that the original spec was ever fully implemented.  Implementations of the Algol-68R spec did eventually appear, but by then other simpler languages were starting to emerge ... like BCPL, C and eventually C++.)

There *are* web frameworks for the Pascal language ... if that is what you are after.  A Google search for "pascal" and "web" shows some apparently relevant hits.  However, I wouldn't recommend going down this path.  Most people would classify Pascal as an "almost dead" language these days.

AFAIK, there is no "web coding program" called Pascal that is any way related to Java.

Comment: Pascal derivative Delphi is still the second best sold IDE to my best knowledge, after the VS family. So unless you mean ancient Pascal, that might be a bit exaggerated.

Comment: @Marco - how many new systems are written in Delphi these days?  Is it trending upwards ... or downwards?  Or just scroll up and look at the SO question counts for Java versus Pascal - 92,281 versus 215.

Comment: Add Delphi in your query. Delphi is decreasing overall, but remains strong in small shops. But nearly everything is decreasing, except the scripting language du jour and C#.

Comment: Hmm. If it needs many questions, is that a good or a bad sign? I have an opinion on that. And SO is heavily biased.

Comment: @Stephan - that's true ... to a point.  SO is not biased *per se*.  Rather, using SO question counts as an indication of popularity (or whatever) is invalid because of selection bias.

Comment: @Marco - increasing / decreasing usage are interesting, but the key issue is the point at which a language-using community reaches (or drops below) the critical mass needed to sustain it and its vendors.

Comment: First, hardly any programming language is actually carried by its userbase. Delphi is an exception. In general the alternatives are owned by the platform provider.  Second, that is a very generalized statement. The problem is that alternatives like .NET are platform specific and often treated as a whole, while in reality all but the major usage (ASP.NET) is very fragmented into separated communities and additional vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no Java is based on the principles of the UCSD Pascal bytecode intepreter system. IIRC Wirth is even named in the original Java VM credits. But that is eighties stuff, and predating the web. It is only interesting if you really want to know the history that lead to Java. (and specially the ideas behind the CPU independance of it)

There are still Pascal web initiatives though, like e.g. [Morfik](http://www.morfik.com/), but they are not really related, and are more backports of Javascript ideas.

Comment: While Wirth deserves huge plaudits for his work, I don't think he was involved in the USCD Pascal project; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCSD_Pascal . Also note that Gosling credits USCD Pascal (not Wirth) as an inspiration for the JVM architecture.

Comment: Wirth formally worked mostly on the M2 variant, Lilith. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith_%28computer%29) but afaik there were many contacts. I'm pretty sure I have seen Wirth in the past, but I haven't kept tabs.  UCSD Pascal backported many M2 features. Note also that the article you reference mentions that the Pcode concept was based on an earlier one from Zurich/Wirth

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Morfik](http://www.morfik.com), a Pascal web framework that produces java script ajax like applications.